# Rails Multiple Params in Different Objects With OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

just wondering what would be the best way to do something like this in rails:

I have 3 tables -> `Events (:id, :name, :category_id, :group_id)`, `Category (:id, :name)`, `Group (:id, :name)`

I need to make a query that works something like -> `SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (category_id = x OR category_id = y ...) AND (group_id = a OR group_id = b ...)`

Basically the way that filters on amazon or ebay work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Wow this was ridiculously easy, I <3 rails!

```
@events = Event.all
if params.has_key?("category_id")
  @events = @events.where("category_id IN(?)", params["category_id"])
end
```

And you can pass multiple values for params as: /events?category_id[]=1&category_id[]=2

Comment: you know that this answer has really little to do with your question?

Answer (score 3):

if i understand you correctly, you are searching for events that are in list of categories or a list of groups.

i would do that like this: `Event.where('category_id IN(?) AND group_id IN(?)', [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`

Comment: yes exactly! how could i do this in the controller though? sorry im still trying to fully understand how params and such work

Comment: erm, what? controller? just write it there?

Comment: sorry, i mean how would i pass the parameters to the controller? for example i would need to receive several variables for category_id and several variables for group_id (currently it's only for 1, 2, 3, etc). I'm still learning how to use parameters in rails

Comment: also, there will be times when no category_id or group_id will be passed, in which case all categories should be sent. how could i deal with that?